# I couldn't access VIOS from browser after installing

Tags: aix

I have installed a VIOS using nimol, install completed successfully but I could access the VIOS from browser.

I am seeing the following error.

```
# /usr/bin/ksh /usr/ios/lpm/sbin/httpdmgr start
ready=12
Error: This is not a management partition.
Done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could also relate to this -

Might indicate VIOS is not in management mode. By default VIOS is in management mode where the web app you are trying works. But somehow if HMC is connected to the CEC (with the VIOS), VIOS is longer is in management mode. Then you will notice this error.  Similar error you will notice when you try with commands like `lssyscfg -r sys`

Now to convert VIOS  back to management mode, you need to set  your power box (where VIOS partition is putting up) to default manufacturing mode. There is procedure to do that.

Primarily you have to access ASM web, remove HMC connection `(ASM ->System configuration ->Hardware Management Consoles->remove )`, do a firmware reset `(Factory Configuration->Reset server firmware settings)`.

Please follow following for exact detail:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1011514

Answer (score 0):

Try this first - 
Have you SSH'd or Telnet'd into the VIOS. Perhaps restarting the HTTP daemon would do the trick.

```
oem_setup_env
```

That command will break you out of the restricted shell, and give you root access on the box.

```
ps -ef | grep http
```

Shows this *"/usr/bin/ksh /usr/ios/lpm/sbin/httpdmgr start"* so issuing a *"restart"* should bring it back up.